# What if someone is being rude but ends up answering correctly?

Tags: discussion, rude-or-abusive

What if someone is being rude in the comments when you mention their answer/edit are not working, but their third attempt of answering is mostly correct?

Do you engage (and ask to improve the answer) or ignore the person answering? Do you reward the rude comments by accepting the answer or downvote it?

I would ask a polite person to fix the answer so I can accept it, but I will probably get another irritated response for free.

Unfortunately I cannot remove questions or add people like this to an ignore list that prevents them from answering/commenting. What is the proper way of discouraging rude behavior?

Comment: Flag the comments. If the answer is helpful, upvote it. Otherwise, you can downvote it or abstain from voting depending how how bad it is. If the answer is also abusive, flag it or edit our the abusive parts.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56583948/revisions) the Q&A? That answer doesn't seem to have received very drastic edits during its lifetime.

Comment: It sucks that someone has to make you feel bad... but it sucks even more that you can't laugh it away. If even Stack Overflow with it's rules and regulations is a problem for you, the rest of the web is pretty vicious. Don't give up trying to harden yourself, use Stack Overflow as training. Laugh and flag friend, laugh and flag.

Comment: People complaining that "you answer does not #@$@ work" are withholding a lot of important information all the time (bordering with lying)… so it is not exactly surprising that one replies with not exactly the most welcoming comments to such accusations. Sample discussion could clarify what happens (as [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583395/how-can-i-combine-ember-bootstrap-and-ember-autoresize/56583948#comment99761396_56583948) found by @yivi don't seem to contain anything "extremely rude" or written by not a "normal person")

Comment: @yivi Exactly. Except I saw it before when happening to someone else's question, and now to my own question it feels a bit more personal. I did not mention said Q&A on purpose because I want to hear advise on how to deal with this without this turning into a witch-hunt or backfiring, as it did either way judging from the downvotes. The answer includes an edit to a working 'twiddle' acompanied by a comment that I am making things up. However, the code in the 'twiddle' is different. I tried all approaches and the first two simply don't work. Which I commented. The twiddle works.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeiLevenkov. Indeed, my comments did not contain any direct or indirect offence, other than mirroring Redsandro's attitude (which  AlexeiLevenkov correctly described in his comment above). Redsandro was quick to call my answer as wrong without making any effort to understand the answer and the problem underlying his question. When he wasn't able to use my answer as-is in his code, without modification, he proceeded with accusations in rudeness. As a result, my comments were deleted without notice. Great job!  PS This comment is likely rude according to Redsandro.

Comment: Not to mention that Redsandro had cross-posted his question in at least three places at once (SO, Ember Discord, `ember-bootstrap` issue queue), violating `ember-bootstrap`'s contributing guidelines.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If someone is really rude, just flag their comments as rude (or as "unkind", if it doesn't really rise to "rude or abusive").

If you find the final version of the answer useful, you can upvote despite their previous behaviour. But it's understandable if you do not feel inclined to do so.

But it's better to separate code of conduct violations (which should be flagged for mods to handle) from quality signals, which we all handle as a community.

And if someone begins being rude towards you, just flag and disengage. Do not spend more time encouraging rude users to behave that way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this (much downvoted) question. I did not know there were multiple flags. I thought they were booleans. I've never flagged someone before, and never curiously peeked out of a worry that I'd get someone in trouble black-and-white style. I've taken mixed/your advise and politely commented what was wrong (again) and flagged some comments as unfriendly.